Extreme Mass Ratio Inspirals and GWs cycles
I was reading through the following paper GRMHD study of accreting massive black hole binaries in astrophysical environment: A review. Therein, we have the following image

It is not quite clear how long Post-Newtonian (PN) theory remains adequate and what distinguishes between an inspiral and a late inspiral. My questions are as follows:

How long does the inspiral phase last before it transitions into a late inspiral phase, rendering PN theory inadequate? In other words, how long do the early to mid-inspiral phases last, and how long does the late inspiral phase run?

Specifically, how long does a late inspiral phase last? In the book "Gravitational-Wave Astronomy: Exploring the Dark Side of the Universe," it is stated that



As an example, a $10M\odot$/$10^{6}M\odot$ system will spend the last few
years of inspiral in a very tight orbit emitting $10^5$ −$10^6$ gravitational-wave cycles in the
LISA band.


How do they determine that the late inspiral lasts this long, and how many gravitational wave cycles are emitted during this period?


incidentally, it remains adequate for longer than it should, according to Will (2011) in "On the unreasonable effectiveness of the post-Newtonian approximation in gravitational physics"! The title alludes to a classic essay by Wigner.

There is no well established taxonomy of dividing the inspiral into "late" and "early" parts. When people do talk about the "late inspiral" they mean "that part of the inspiral in which the PN approximation is inadequate." Where that is depends on a combination of things including the parameters of the binary (mass-ratio, spins, etc.), the order of the PN approximation, and how accurate you need the final answer.
For equal mass, non-spinning binaries, and if you don't need a particularly accurate answer a 3PN approximation can be accurate enough for the entire inspiral phase (and you need full Numerical Relativity only for the final plunge and merger.)
This changes a lot when the mass-ratio becomes smaller. One of the effects of making the mass-ratio smaller is that the (specific) energy lost to gravitational waves also becomes smaller, and binary evolves slower, completing more gravitational wave cycles during the inspiral. A consequence of this is that you need to know the energy lost per GW cycle much more accurately. Specifically, the accumulated error in the gravitational wave phase scales roughly with the reciprocal of the (symmetric) mass-ratio $\nu$. Consequently, if we want the inspiral to stay roughly in phase all through the inspiral, this means that we can tolerate an relative error in the energy flux that is rough $O(\nu)$.
For $\nu=10^{-5}$, the relative error in the 5.5PN flux (chosen simply because I had the plot at hand) for quasicircular non-spinning binaries becomes larger than $10^{-5}$ at a separation of roughly $25 GM/c^2$. So, in this case the part of the inspiral between $25 GM/c^2$ and the last stable orbit ($6 GM/c^2$) can be considered "late inspiral". Since the shrinkage of the orbit is $O(\nu)$ per orbital cycles, this means that the binary $\nu=10^{-5}$ completes $O(10/\nu) \approx 10^6$ orbital cycles in the "late inspiral". These are very rough "back of the envelope" estimates. They can be made more precise by looking at numerical simulations of such inspirals, e.g. using the publicly available fast EMRI waveforms package, which uses interpolate numerical data obtained in the small mass-ratio limit.
Edit:
Below is a plot showing the relative difference between the linear in $\nu$ part of the the energy flux to its $n$PN approximation as a function of the "compactness" ($GM/(c^2r)$) of the binary, using PN approximations available from the Black Hole Perturbation toolkit, and numerical data I generated myself.


Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I have two more questions:
Is it possible to further model the late inspiral phase by incorporating additional PN terms?
Could you provide a reference for the relative error in the 5.5PN flux?
Thank you again!

It is not clear that adding more PN terms would lead to an improvement due to the asymptotic nature of the PN series. You can probably improve at least a bit though. The 5.5PN statement came from private data, but you should be able to reproduce it from public data from the black hole perturbation toolkit, which has numerical flux data: https://github.com/BlackHolePerturbationToolkit/CircularOrbitSelfForceData and data of the corresponding PN expressions and data for the corresponding PN approximations: https://bhptoolkit.org/PostNewtonianSelfForce/

Thank you! I apologize if I am being bothersome, but I am having trouble reproducing results using Mathematica and the BlackHolePerturbationToolkit. Could you please post the figure using the public data?

I've added the plot to the post above. The "late inspiral" regime keeps shrinking with increasing PN order until it essentially vanishes at 21.5PN order. Note that as we look further in the strong field regime there is no discernible improvement from going to higher PN order at $r=4GM/c^2$. This is a problem when we consider binaries with spins, which have a much smaller LSO.

Thank you very much!
